# How to Insert, Update, Delete in a one to many relationship?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My problem is i don't know How to Insert, Update, Delete in a one to many relationship.
It's been my problem since when i put a relationship in my tables in database.

[image]

Am I just going to modify this codes?

```
Dim sqlinsert As String = "INSERT INTO tblExtra(InfoID, Company, Status, Religion, Province)  VALUES ('" & txtinfoid.text & "', '" & txtcom.Text & "','" &  txtstat.Text & "','" & txtrel.Text & "','" &  txtpro.Text & "')"


            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@InfoID", txtinfoid.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Company", txtcom.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Status", txtstat.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Religion", txtrel.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Province", txtpro.Text))




            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted")
```

thanks for your help in advance btw i`m using visual studio 2008.

Comment: what is your problem? what is not working? are you getting any errors?

Comment: ah sorry i copied the wrong codes but i already edit the question. When i`m inserting a record in tblExtra i`m getting a error : You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblExtra'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you have relation on infoId. The insert is failing because the InfoId you are inserting is not present in tblInfo. Enter valid InfoId in table "tblExtra"

Hope it helps.

By the way your insert query should be like this

```
Dim sqlinsert As String = "INSERT INTO tblExtra(InfoID, Company, Status, Religion, Province) VALUES (@InfoID,@Company,@Status,@Religion,@Province)"
```

Comment: sorry this error is new to me so i can`t understand. can u explain more?

Comment: @namikaze2o When you enter infoId in txtInfoId textbox, check if that infoid is present in tblInfo

Comment: yes it is present in tblInfo. and i`m entering the same record in tblExtra that is in the tblInfo - InfoID column.

Comment: @namikaze2o Make sure that the default for the foreign key field is not 0. Also make sure that the foreign key's required property is set to yes

Comment: @namikaze2o What is column type for InfoId in both tables?

Comment: same Number data type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46719/discussion-between-ashreva-and-namikaze2o)